# Pythonic way to apply a filter to a table

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables. A data table and a filter table. I want to apply the filter table on the data table to select only certain records. When the filter table has a # in a column, the filter is ignored. Additionally, multiple selections can be applied using a | separator.

I have achieved this using a for loop with a bunch of & and | conditions. However, given that my filter table is quite large, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this. My filter table looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

f = {'business':['FX','FX','IR','IR','CR'],
     'A/L':['A','L','A','L','#'],
     'Company':['207|401','#','#','207','#']}
filter = pd.DataFrame(data=f)
filter
```

and the data table looks like:

```
d = {'business': ['FX','a','CR'],
     'A/L': ['A','A','L'],
     'Company': ['207','1','2']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data
```

finally the filter looks like:

```
for counter in range (0, len(filter)):
    businessV = str(filter.iat[counter,0])
    ALV = str(filter.iat[counter,1])
    CompanyV = str(filter.iat[counter,2])


    businessV1 = businessV.split("|", 100)
    ALV1 = ALV.split("|", 100)
    CompanyV1 = CompanyV.split("|", 100)

    businessV2 = ('#' in businessV1)| (data['business'].isin(businessV1))
    ALV2 = ('#' in ALV1)|(data['A/L'].isin(ALV1))
    CompanyV2 = ('#' in CompanyV1)| (data['Company'].isin(CompanyV1))

    final_filter = businessV2 & ALV2 & CompanyV2
    print(final_filter)
```

I am trying to find a more efficient way to select the first and last rows in the data table using the filters in the filter table.

Specifically, I am wondering how to :

1. Handle cases when the filter table has quite a few more columns
2. The current code goes through each row in the data table once for each row in the filter table. For large data sets, this takes way too much time and does not seem very efficient to me.

Comment: If the number of distinct business, A/L and Company values in the business table limited (for example I would assume that A/L can only be A or L, but what about the other 2 columns)?

Comment: there are certain columns where the number of data values is limited. As you point out, A/L can be either A or L. However, certain other columns ( like company) can have a very large set of valid values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a rather complex question. I would start by pre-processing the filter table to have only one value per field by duplicating rows containing `'|'`. In order to limit the number of useless rows, I would first replace anything containing a `'#'` and other values with a single `'#'`.

Once this is done, it is possible to select the rows from the business table with a `merge`, provided merging on the columns containing no sharp.

Code could be:

```
# store the original column names
cols = filter.columns
# remove any alternate value if a # is already present:
tosimp = pd.DataFrame({col: filter[col].str.contains('#')&
                       filter[col].str.contains('\|')
                       for col in cols})

# add a column to store in a (hashable) tuple the columns with no '#'
filter['wild'] = filter.apply(lambda x: tuple(col for col in cols
                                             if x[col] != '#'), axis=1)

# now explode the fields containing a '|'
tosimp = pd.DataFrame({col: filter[col].str.contains('\|')
                       for col in filter.columns})

# again, store in a new column the columns containing a '|'
tosimp['wild'] = filter.apply(lambda x: tuple(col for col in cols
                                             if '|' in filter.loc[x.name, col]),
                              axis=1)

# compute a new filter table with one single value per field (or #)
# by grouping on tosimp['wild']
dfl = [filter[tosimp['wild'].astype(str)=='()']]
for k, df in filter[tosimp['wild'].astype(str)!='()'].groupby(tosimp['wild']):
    for ix, row in df.iterrows():
        tmp = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.loc[ix, col].split('|')
                                          for col in k], names=k).to_frame(None)
        l = len(tmp)
        dfl.append(pd.DataFrame({col: tmp[col]
                                 if col in k else [row[col]] * l
                                 for col in filter.columns}))

filter2 = pd.concat(dfl)

# Ok, we can now use that new filter table to filter the business table
result = pd.concat([data.merge(df, on=k, suffixes=('', '_y'),
                               right_index=True)[cols]
                    for k, df in filter2.groupby('wild')]).sort_index()
```

Limits:

- the pre-processing iterates on group by dataframes and uses a `iterrows` call: it can take some time on a large filter table
- the current algo does not handle at all a line containing `'#'` in all of its fields. If it is a possible use case, it must be searched before any other processing. Anyway in that case any row from the business table will be kept.

---

Explaination of the `pd.concat(...` line:

- `[... for k, df in filter2.groupby('wild')]`: split the filter dataframe in sub-dataframes each having a different `wild` values, that is a different set of non # fields
- `data.merge(df, on=k, suffixes=('', '_y'), right_index=True)`: merge each sub filter dataframe with the data dataframe on the non # fields, that is select the rows from the data dataframe matching one of these filter rows. Keep the original index of the data dataframe
- `...[cols]` keep only the relevant fields
- `pd.concat(...)` concat all those partial dataframes
- `... .sort_index()` sort the concatenated dataframe according to its index which is by construction the index of the original data dataframe

Comment: can you help by clarifying the following piece of code:result = pd.concat([data.merge(df, on=k, suffixes=('', '_y'),
                               right_index=True)[cols]
                    for k, df in filter2.groupby('wild')]).sort_index()

Comment: Sorry to trouble you so much on this same question. However, can you point me to some documentation of how [cols] is used with pd.merge ?

Comment: @NumberLogic `[cols]` restrict the merged dataframe to the list of original columns and discards the duplicated columns. Just try what happens when you do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your problem is that you want the all the first matches for `business,A/L` with a `Company` that is specified (or any if `#` is used) in the corresponding filter.

I'm supposing that your intended result is a dataframe with just the first row of `data`. When your filter gets large, you can speed things up by using a join operation on the filter and keep only the first result.

```
# Split on | so that every option is represented in a single row
filter0 = filter.set_index(['business','A/L']).Company.str.split('|',expand=True).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2',axis=1).rename(columns={0:'Company'})

# The set of *all* rows in data which are caught by filters with a Company specification
r1 = data.merge(filter0[filter0.Company != '#'])

# The set of *all* rows in data which are caught by filters allowing for *any* Company
r2 = data.merge(filter0[filter0.Company == '#'].drop('Company', axis=1))

# r1 and r2 are not necessarily disjoint, and each one may have multiple rows that pass one filter
# Take the union, sort on the index to preserve the original ordering,
# then finally drop duplicates of business+A/L, keeping only the first entry
pd.concat([r1,r2]).drop_duplicates(subset=['business','A/L'], keep='first')
```

With regard to your case in handling multiple columns on the filter: A single row in your filter would essentially say something along the lines of,

"I want `field1=foo` AND `field2=bar` AND `field3=baz1 OR field3=baz2` AND `field4=qux1 OR field4=qux2`."

The main idea is to expand this into a multiple rows composed of only AND conditinals, so in this case it would be to turn it into four rows of

`field1=foo` AND `field2=bar` AND `field3=baz1` AND `field4=qux1`

`field1=foo` AND `field2=bar` AND `field3=baz1` AND `field4=qux2`

`field1=foo` AND `field2=bar` AND `field3=baz2` AND `field4=qux1`

`field1=foo` AND `field2=bar` AND `field3=baz2` AND `field4=qux2`

In other words, use `.split` and `.stack` multiple times, once for each column with an OR condition. This may be slightly inefficient (you might get better speed and code readability using `itertools.product` somewhere), but your bottleneck is usually in the join operation, so this isn't too much of a worry as far as speed is concerned.

Comment: Hi. Perhaps I was not clear enough in my initial question. I want the output to be flexible. So , in the  revised data set, I need the first and last rows in the data table

Comment: I like your approach ! However it works only with # for company. I'll try and rack my brains to see if I can expand it for other columns as well